# Memory allocation in c++ using separate funciton

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, reference

I have cplusplus code to make singly linked list.

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};
```

Using the following function:

```
static void push_list(struct ListNode*& _head, int _val)
{

    if (NULL == _head)
        _head = new ListNode(_val);

    else{
        ListNode* tmp = _head->next;
        while (tmp != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp = new ListNode(_val);
    }
}
```

However, it allocates only one element and head->next stays NULL.

The function is called as follows:

```
static void MakeList(void)
{
    ListNode* l1 = NULL;
    push_list(l1, 1);
    push_list(l1, 2);
    push_list(l1, 3);
    push_list(l1, 4);
}
```

Comment: You should step through your code with a debugger.  That should help you to understand why the code is misbehaving from your expectation.

Comment: When the line `tmp = new ListNode(_val);` is executed, `tmp` only contains a copy of the `NULL` pointer at the end of the list. Changing the value of this copy does not change the original value stored at the end of the linked list. Therefore, you probably want to make `tmp` a double pointer or a reference to a pointer, as you did with the `_head` parameter.

Comment: Just use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list or even better; std::vector.

Comment: On a side note, you should not be mixing `NULL` and `nullptr`.  Since you have `nullptr` available, you should be using that everywhere, not using `NULL` at all.  `nullptr` was invented to *replace* NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Your `push_list()` is implemented wrong.

When `_head` is null, you create a new node and assign it to `_head`.  OK so far.

But on subsequent calls, when `_head` is not null, you are assigning  `_head->next` to `tmp`, and `_head->next` will be null when the list has 1 node.  So, your `while` loop doesn't do anything, leaving `tmp` set to null (even if the list had more than 1 node in it, your loop would eventually reach the last node and set `tmp` to its `next`, thus `tmp` will always end up being null whether the loop is entered or not).  Then you create a new node and assign it to `tmp` only, not to the `next` field of the last node in the list.  So, you have leaked the new node, and `_head->next` remains null for the next time `push_list()` is called, causing the same problem again and again.

To fix this, you need to tweak your loop to find the last node in the list, and then you can assign the new node to that last node's `next` field, eg:

```cpp
static void push_list(ListNode* &_head, int _val)
{
    if (!_head)
        _head = new ListNode(_val);
    else{
        ListNode* tmp = _head; // <-- not _head->next !
        while (tmp->next) { // <-- while there is still another node in the list...
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        // tmp now points to the last node, not to null !
        tmp->next = new ListNode(_val);
    }
}
```

---

`push_list()` can then be simplified much further by using a slightly different, more optimized, looping strategy:

```cpp
static void push_list(ListNode* &_head, int _val)
{
    ListNode** tmp = &_head;
    while (*tmp) {
        tmp = &((*tmp)->next);
    }
    *tmp = new ListNode(_val);
}
```

This loop finds the first `ListNode*` pointer that is null, and then assigns a new node to that pointer.  This way, you don't have to treat `_head` separately.  Either the `_head` itself will be null, or the `next` field of the last node in the list will be null.  This first-available null is where you want to insert your new node.